# invoke method by List object as string

Tags: c#

I want to invoke method from a object in list by a string data for method, and for object/class, params, ..

```
class MyClass{
    List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
    public MyClass(){        
        elements[0] = new Element();
        //elements[0].MyMethod();

        InvokeMet(this, "MyMethod", "elements[0]")
    }
}
class Fun()
{
    public static void InvokeMet(object obj, string method, string instance)
    {
        string[] par = {};
        string[] instance_array = instance.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' });    
        object instanceObjectList = obj.GetType().GetField(instance_array[0]).GetValue(obj);
        object instanceObject = ((List<Element>)instanceObjectList)[Convert.ToInt32(instance_array[1])];            
        MethodInfo mi = instanceObject.GetType().GetMethod(method);
        mi.Invoke(instanceObject, par);
    }
}
```

It is working, but I want the type of list to be dynamic, eg. obtained from object

```
object instanceObject = ((List<instanceObjectList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]>)instanceObjectList);
```

or maybe it can be obtained from a string

```
String cl = "Element";
object instanceObject = ((List<typeFromString(cl)>)instanceObjectList);
```

How can I do it?
Maybe it can be done completely differently?

Comment: This code is potentially slow and error prone. So I need to ask, what's the bigger picture here? Why do you want to do this? What is making this type of call valuable to you?

Comment: In concept of program I want to call method via sending txt msg via sockets.. So I want to send: instance, method, parameters.. And call sth like this: "instance"."method"("parameters"); but instance could be element of list.

Answer (score 1):

why not just doing it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
    public MyClass()
    {
        elements[0] = new Element();
        //elements[0].MyMethod();

        Fun.InvokeMet(elements[0], "MyMethod");
    }
}
class Fun
{
    public static void InvokeMet(object obj, string method)
    {
        string[] par = { };
        MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod(method);
        if (mi != null)
            mi.Invoke(obj, par);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to dynamically choose the list and indexed item from a string too. I just don't know why he wants to do that.

Comment: I want to call by strings only except instance of calling class.. I know that I could to this by objects, but in the context of whole program I need strings solution.